# Best way to install ubuntu on Asus Eee PC 901 with 4GB Boot SLC and 16GB MLC drive

Tags: system-installation, asus

The 4GB is faster, but the 16GB has the space.  What is the best way to install while taking advantage of the strengths of both.  I have it installed on the 4GB, but worthless because I can't install apps, or upgrade.  Is there a way to put the apps drive on 16GB, but use 4GB for booting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. You can even do that without setting up a new system.

Create an ext4 partition on your designated boot drive and copy the contents of your `/boot` directory onto that partition. Then, update your `/etc/fstab` to include the newly created partition and run `update-grub`. The official Ubuntu help site has [a more in-depth tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CreateBootPartitionAfterInstall).

If you feel uncomfortable doing all that manually, there's the option of [using BootRepair to do the heavy lifting for you](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in my experiences in doing this:

https://coosoft.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/installing-ubuntu-on-an-asus-eee-901-pc/

Basically I have the OS on the 4GiB SSD but enough space to install applications and do updates etc.